# Android 6.0 Fingerprint Authentication using setUserAuthentication(true) errors

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, fingerprint

I have an implementation of fingerprint authentication that has been running fine until I ran it on a HTC M9+  (Android 6.0).

I have a key generated in the AndroidKeyStore:

```
        mKeyPairGenerator.initialize(
                new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(KEY_ALIAS, KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT)
                        .setDigests(KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA256, KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA512)
                        .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_RSA_OAEP)
                        .setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)
                        .build());
        mKeyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
```

I attempt to then use that to initialize a cipher for the fingerprint auth call and on the HTC running 6.0 Android I get an error:

```
Crypto primitive not backed by AndroidKeyStore provider
```

Now I understand that there is a bug in API 23 that does not allow use of the public key without authentication (Even though it should) so I implemented code to extract the key from the AndroidKeyStore item and then init it  (Per suggestion in the Android documentation).  That works just fine.

But I cannot use that extracted public key cipher/crypto object for the fingerprint auth call:

```
m_fingerprintManager.authenticate(m_cryptoObject, m_cancellationSignal, 0, this, null)
```

If I do not extract the public key for the init and use it straight from the AndroidKeyStore I get an error stating that the user is not authenticated.

Here is the code for initCipher extracting the public key:

```
            PublicKey key = mKeyStore.getCertificate(KEY_ALIAS).getPublicKey();

            PublicKey unrestricted = KeyFactory.getInstance(key.getAlgorithm())
                    .generatePublic(new X509EncodedKeySpec(key.getEncoded()));

            OAEPParameterSpec spec = new OAEPParameterSpec(
                    "SHA-256", "MGF1", MGF1ParameterSpec.SHA1, PSource.PSpecified.DEFAULT);

            mCipher.init(opmode, unrestricted, spec);
```

Here is the code just taking straight from the keystore:

```
PrivateKey key = (PrivateKey) mKeyStore.getKey(KEY_ALIAS, null);
            mCipher.init(opmode, key);
```

Using the extracted public returns the error that it is not backed by the AndroidKeyStore.

Using the key directly from the store returns an error that the user is not authenticated.

So, how do I get this to work?  As mentioned using the key directly from the keystore has worked fine on other devices (Samsung S7 Edge with Android M and N, Nexus 6P with N, Samsung S6 with M (6.0.1), and others)

Comment: After you've gone to the trouble of getting the public key out so you can use it without authentication (to work around the bug), why are you then using it with the fingerprint manager, which is all about authentication? (BTW, glad to see people using OAEP and good digests.)

Comment: From what I have read, I need to have the user authentication set to true so that when fingerprints are added or the screen lock, etc. has been changed I will get an invalidation exception.  This works on all phone tested but the HTC M9.  On the HTC M9 phone, I get an exception that the user is not authenticated when I try to init the cipher.  How can I use the cipher when I am assuming the fingerprint manager does the authentication?  It is like a chicken before the egg.  I need to init it to use it in the fingerprint auth but I have to be authenticated on the HTC M9 to init it.